# Add an add entry button to my Plugin in Craft CP

Tags: plugins, control-panel, cp-dashboard

Hey I'm writing my first Craft plugin and would like to add a button to have a dialog box in [image: Choose an entry]. I want to create a link to a page entry with this and save it to the database.

This is the code I want to extend in my template:

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

    <div class="" style="width: 50%">
        <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="glossary/entry/saveEntry">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="glossary">
            {{ forms.textField({
               label: 'Glossary Entry'|t,
               instructions: 'Enter a new Word'|t,
               id: 'entry',
               name: 'entry',
               value: ''}) }}
            <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Submit'|t }}">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is the elementSelect field type which Craft bundles with the CMS. You can find the template of this field in `craft/app/templates/_includes/elementSelect.html`

Here's a quick example that will get you started:

```
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
    label: 'Select An Entry'|t,
    instructions: 'Select...'|t,
    id: 'entry',
    name: 'entry',
    elementType: craft.elements.getElementType("Entry"),
    source: '',
    criteria: '',
    sourceElementId: '',
    elements: '',
    storageKey: '',
    viewMode: 'list',
    limit: 1
 }) }}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll check that!  Where is the doc for this stuff?

Comment: @SimonMüller No problem. As far as I know there isn't any, it's just from my experience of reverse engineering these fields previously.